# Setting domain for double integral

Tags: multiple-integral

I am given the following integral
$\iint (x^2+y^2)e^{x^2+y^2} dxdy$ and the domain D={(x,y)| $1\le x^2+y^2 \le 4$}

And I am asked to compute the integral, I think I know how to compute it, but I am having trouble setting it up.

Comment: The Domain is an annulus, so convert to Polar coordinates. Then the bounds on $(r, \theta)$ should be obvious.

Comment: In general circles -> polar coordinates :-)

Comment: When you say you are having difficulty, can you be more clear? Did you draw it? The region is between two circles $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 4$. Have you worked with polar coordinates before?

Comment: I have briefly heard of polar coordinates at a lecture but I am not sure how to work with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use polarcoordinates as follow:

Let us consider the change of coordinates given by:
$$ x=r \cos \theta ,\, y=r \sin \theta $$  then the Jacobian (intuitively this is the small deformation in the space that occur by our change of variable) of this transformation is given by $$\begin{vmatrix} \cos \theta & -r \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{vmatrix}=r$$

Now for change the elements of our integral let us consider this useful fact

$$x^2+y^2=r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta=r^2(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta)=r^2$$
that help us to change and remplace in the integral the expression $x^2+y^2$.

Now we are ready for change our integral (which is only switch all in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ with the respectively small change in the deformation *The Jacobian* and our new region of integration) to a new integral which is easy of calculate, for this task let us calculate how looks our new domain $W$.

Since $D$ is given by  $D=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid 1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 4\rbrace$ then by our change of variable it stay like
$$W=\lbrace (r,\theta)\mid 1\leq r^2\leq 4 \rbrace $$

Now our integral is
$$\iint_W r^2 e^{r^2} r d \theta d r= \int_1^2 \int_0^{2\pi} r^3 e^{r^2} d \theta dr=2\pi \int_{1}^{2}r^3 e^{r^2}dr= 2\pi \frac{3}{2}e^4=3\pi e^4$$

Comment: I understand what you did, but what told you you have to work with polar coordinates? is it the $x^2+y^2$ ?

Comment: I edite the post

Comment: Yes, usually when you see the squares $x^2+y^2$ the poolarcoordinates reduce it to a simple expresion like $r^2$

Comment: In other cases when you have expression like $x-y$ and $y^3+y^2$ not is the best way, since if you use this change of variable you get other integral more hard of calculate, and for this reason you should search other more usefull change of variable like $x(u,v),y(u,v)$ and work with this and their respective deformation(Jacobian) and see if the new region and integral are easy of calculate

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Your very welcome i´m glad of can help you.

Comment: How are you so very sure that the integral is to be evaluated over the first quadrant of the annulus?

Comment: I'm evaluating it in all the quadrant's since I take $r$ Frome $1$ to $2$ and theta Frome $0$ to $ 2 \pi$